# Optimización de extracción de xml en php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, xml, webservice

os expongo el problema:

- Estoy obteniendo datos de un xml extremadamente grande y lo estoy insertando en mi base de datos, lo realizo con simplexml. En el servidor en el que voy a alojarlo no puedo aumentarle el memory limit ni el max execution time, debo utilizar la configuración por defecto. Creo que lo que pasa es que me lanza el internal server porque se agota la ram del servidor. Me han recomendado extraer los datos del xml por lotes para no colapsar el servidor.

¿Me recomendáis alguna forma de realizar esto?

Comment: ¿Cuánto pesa el fichero? Podrías poner una parte para ver su estructura?

Comment: podrías mostrar el código con que estás trayendo y luego parseando el XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mientras el OP no explique cómo se está trayendo y parseando los datos, no es posible dar una solución específica. Pero a modo de solución general por si alguien tiene el mismo problema:

[SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/es/book.simplexml.php) carga todo el contenido del XML en memoria. Ahí ya tienes una alerta roja. Puedes ver un ejemplo en este [fiddle](https://www.tehplayground.com/F0uVamBmBdRsexEf)

Aunque sea un archivo de (digamos) 50MB, que no debiera ser tanto para PHP, si el XML tiene muchos nodos entrará en acción el [garbage collector](http://php.net/manual/es/features.gc.php) de PHP. Según [este artículo](http://mimi.kaktusteam.de/blog-posts/2012/01/simplexml-and-php-allowed-memory-size-exchausted-fatal-error/), es el garbage collector el que hace fallar el script por memoria. En él se propone deshabilitar el garbage collector usando [gc_disable](http://php.net/manual/es/function.gc-disable.php). A lo mejor tu hosting no lo permite.

La solución más recomendada es usar [XMLReader](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php). Con éste podrías, primero, descargar el archivo XML completo a la máquina (por ejemplo lo guardas en `/path/to/data.xml`), y luego abrirlo con

```
$reader = new XMLReader();  

//load the selected XML file to the DOM  
$reader->open( '/path/to/data.xml' );  

while ($reader->read()) { 
  ... parseas los nodos y los insertas en la BBDD ...
}
```

De hecho, para no tener que cambiar mucho tu sintaxis, incluso puedes [combinar XMLReader con SimpleXML](http://biostall.com/import-frickin-huge-xml-files-with-xmlreader-and-simplexml/).

Lo importante es que XMLReader::read irá leyendo los nodos del archivo uno por uno, sin almacenar más que un nodo en memoria. El garbage collector no se meterá a hacer sus cálculos compitiendo por el uso de recursos.

Sin embargo esto no aborda de lleno el problema del `max_execution_time`. En el mejor de los casos, la superioridad de XMLReader te permitiría soslayar el problema sin topar con el tiempo límite. En caso contrario, el primer paso a optimizar sería la velocidad de inserción en la base de datos. Por ejemplo, construir una sentencia preparada antes de parsear el XML y luego ejecutarla en cada bucle en vez de gatillar un insert separado por cada iteración.

Comment: Llevas mucha razón en tus palabras,  porque me he descargado el xml del web service y pesa 3 megas, es más por los nodos, y en concreto creo que se queda colgado por la descarga de las imágenes en el servidor , ¿podría ser?, de hecho en el bucle en el que leo los nodos, obtengo una imagen y la descargo. ¿Cómo me recomiendas descargarla para que sufra menos el servidor? . Voy a probar lo del xml reader a ver que tal, ya te cuento.

Comment: Yo optaría por guardar la url de la imagen en la BBDD y luego, en otro llamado, recorrer los registros que tengan una URL distinta a tu local, traer la imagen y actualizar el registro. Por ejemplo podrías traer todos los registros, actualizar sólo 30 o 50, y devolver al browser cuántos faltan. Si todavía faltan, gatillar una llamada ajax que repita el proceso hasta que se haya descargado todo. Es mejor separar un problema grande en varios pequeños.

Comment: Gracias, esto me ha servido de mucha ayuda, es la respuesta correcta.